# Data not passed correctly from Laravel controller to blade view **ONLY IN PRODUCTION**

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, composer-php, laravel-blade

```html
//profile.blade.php

<form action="{{ $isFollowing ? route('unfollow', $user->username) : route('follow', $user->username) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit">{{ $isFollowing ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow' }}</button>
</form>
```

```php
// ProfileController.php

public function index()
{
    $reqUsername = request()->route()->parameter('username');

    $user = User::where('username', $reqUsername)
        ->with(['followers', 'records' => function($query) {
            $query->with('likes');
        }])
        ->firstOrFail();

    if ($user->followers->count()) {
        foreach ($user->followers as $follower) {
            $isFollowing = $follower->id == auth()->id();
        }
    } else {
        $isFollowing = false;
    }

    return view('users.profile', [
        'user' => $user,
        'isFollowing' => $isFollowing
    ]);
}
```

I have recently encountered a problem with my Laravel application when deployed to Heroku. Just to note, this has been working just fine in production until very recently. The above snippets still work as intended in dev using Laravel Valet; However, in production, the `$isFollowing` variable is always returned to the view as bool(false) regardless of whether the data shows that the user whose profile we are on is being followed by the currently authenticated user.

Things I have tried thus far;

1. `dd($isFollowing)` in production. Where I would expect that this would show either true or false when we hit the route, in production, I am seeing false preceded by a caret character => `^ False`.
2. Explicitly setting all conditional values and comparisons i.e. `if ($user->followers->count() > 0)` rather than `if ($user->followers->count())`.

What I am currently looking into;

1. Could an update to one of the composer packages (or PHP/Laravel/Composer versions) have caused this issue? I haven't made any changes to these myself so maybe this could have been an automatic update on Heroku's part?

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: Can you please confirm that `dd` of any other variable or static value dump with `^`?

Comment: I can confirm that the caret character is evident in other variables too. Example `dd($user->username)` dumps `^ "my_username"`

Comment: In any file you added `^` by mistake. Try to find in whole project. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Like I explained in the OP, this issue is only evident on the production server and the `$isFollowing` variable is the only piece of data in the application that is not pulling through to the view. This makes me think that the caret issue in `dd()` is not causing the problem as other pieces of data such as the user and the count of followers is coming through just fine. I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Comment: If that worked for a while, but does not any longer, what has changed? Did you upgrade the PHP version, or the Laravel version, or anything else on that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't figure out what was causing this bug but a slight change to my controller code seems to have fixed the issue.

```php
public function index()
{
    $reqUsername = request()->route()->parameter('username');

    $user = User::where('username', $reqUsername)
        ->with(['followers', 'records' => function($query) {
            $query->with('likes');
        }])
        ->firstOrFail();

        return view('users.profile', [
            'user' => $user,
            'isFollowing' => $user->followers->contains('id', auth()->id())
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: As you are loop over your variable so might be it makes it first true and then again false. So you need to break once you find it true.

Comment: I think you have got it there. The issue only seems to have become a problem as the number of users increased. Refactoring to use `$user->followers->contains` has fixed the issue. Thanks.